# How can I use a legacy ssh-rsa key on CentOS 9 Stream?

Tags: centos, ssh

I am setting up a new CentOS 9 Stream container as a part of a CI system. It needs to make an SSH connection to download some code from a legacy Git host using an `ssh-rsa` key (which is considered an acceptable risk on this network with this host).

I start by generating a key.

```
ssh-keygen -t ssh-rsa -f test_rsa_key
```

Running with the key I get a "no mutual signature algorithm" error.

```
ssh -v -i test_rsa_key user@server
```

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: test_rsa_key RSA SHA256:<snip> explicit
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
user@server: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I can explicitly enable `ssh-rsa` with `-oPubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa`, but now I get a libcrypto error.

```
ssh -oPubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa -v -i test_rsa_key user@server
```

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: test_rsa_key RSA SHA256:<snip> explicit
debug1: Server accepts key: test_rsa_key RSA SHA256:<snip> explicit
debug1: identity_sign: sshkey_sign: error in libcrypto
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "test_rsa_key": error in libcrypto
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
user@server: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Is it possible that support for the legacy `ssh-rsa` signature method is disabled in CentOS 9 Stream at the libcrypto level? How can I make a  connection with this key on the latest CentOS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found an answer, courtesy of a [similar issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2061607) somebody else had on the Red Hat Bugzilla.

The issue is caused by the deprecation of SHA1. You can work around this by setting a crypto policy of `DEFAULT:SHA1` (to only re-enable SHA-1) or `LEGACY` (for compatibility with even older things) following the instructions [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/security_hardening/using-the-system-wide-cryptographic-policies_security-hardening#proc_re-enabling-sha-1_using-the-system-wide-cryptographic-policies).

The command is:

```
update-crypto-policies --set DEFAULT:SHA1
```

or

```
update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY
```

Before running, review the linked page because `LEGACY` does enable some quite old crypto settings, which might be too insecure for your use-case.

Comment: I see that at this moment, CENTOS Stream 9 has default crypto policies of `DEFAULT:SHA1` while RHEL 9.2 has `DEFAULT`. Does it mean that the default policy in RHEL 9.3 will be `DEFAULT:SHA1`?

Answer (score 5):

The use of SHA-1 for signatures is restricted in the default crypto policy.

Trying to SSH from RHEL9 (or variant) client to a RHEL6 (or variant) OpenSSH server fails with the following error message:

```
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 1.2.3.4 port 22: error in libcrypto
```

There are 2 known options:

1. [On RHEL9, enable legacy SHA1 crypto-policy](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6816771) (NOT RECOMMENDED):

```shell
update-crypto-policies --set DEFAULT:SHA1
```

2. [On RHEL6, use the ECDSA algorithm instead of RSA to create the host key](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/711953) (preferred)

   i. Generate sshd ECDSA host keys:

   ```shell
   ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 384 -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
   semanage fcontext -a -f -- -t sshd_key_t /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
   semanage fcontext -a -f -- -t sshd_key_t /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
   ```

   ii. Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and set:

   ```
   HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
   ```

   iii. Restart `sshd`

   ```shell
   service sshd restart
   ```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  The #2 option is the appropriate solution as the other solutions enable weak crypto.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn’t answer the question. It answers another good question (how can I upgrade my legacy RHEL 6 system to use modern crypto?). Unfortunately, that’s not the question here. In my case, I do not have control over the other system — I’m not even sure what distro it’s using — I just know that it only supports bad crypto and I have to work with it.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't locked in to an RSA keypair, you can use ECDSA instead.

In my case I was running into this same error while attempting to SSH from an RHEL 9 client to an RHEL 6 server.  I was able to solve this issue by generating and using an ECDSA keypair instead of RSA:

```
ssh-keygen -t ecdsa
ssh user@host -i ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
```

Another answer mentions generating ECDSA host keys on the server.  In my case, the RHEL 6 server was already using ECDSA host keys.

With the ECDSA keypair and host keys, it was not necessary for me to set the "legacy" crypto policy as mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

In my context, I have a RHEL5 system, a Centos 6.9 system and a Centos 6.6 system. I'm working to build a replacement for the Centos 6.9 system on new hardware with Rocky 9. I need to run SSH in from and to each of the old systems from the Rocky 9 system.

The ecdsa key replacement worked for connection to the Centos systems from the Rocky 9 system, but not to the RHEL5 system. And I was still unable to connect from the old systems tp Rpcly 9. Along the way, I did variations of the suggestion in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674582/how-to-enable-ssh-rsa-in-sshd-of-openssh-8-8 which changed the symptoms but didn't fix the issues.

The final change which seems to have fixed my connection issues was the

> update-crypto-policies --set DEFAULT:SHA1

command described above.