# How to enable legacy ciphers in modern SSH client

Tags: centos, ssh, redhat, oracle-linux

Got a shiny new OL9 and I need to connect to some legacy servers, as in CentOS 5.

The OL9 SSH client does not support the legacy ciphers that CentOS 5 supports:

```
[opc@vm1 ~]$ ssh legacyServer
Unable to negotiate with 10.0.0.138 port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

After looking at this page: [OpenSSH Legacy Options](https://www.openssh.com/legacy.html)

Tried this way:

```
[opc@vm1 ~]$ ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 legacyServer
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 10.0.0.138 port 22: error in libcrypto
```

My hope is that I'm missing something else in `/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends` to enable legacy ciphers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer thanks to this:
[How can I use a legacy ssh-rsa key on CentOS 9 Stream?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1095898/how-can-i-use-a-legacy-ssh-rsa-key-on-centos-9-stream)
And this:
[ssh failed on almaLinux 9 with openssl 3.0.1 (error in libcrypto) #18420](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/18420)

The solution for me is to run this, as root:
`update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY`

Which is a Python tool that changes `/etc/crypto-policies`, mainly by changing the symlinks from `/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/` to the different profiles in `/usr/share/crypto-policies/back-ends`.